# WPF binding to an observable collection with hash key as index

Tags: wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

The following code:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="MyProgram.Views.MyControlContainer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProgram.Views"
             xmlns:common_model="clr-namespace:MyProgram.Models;assembly=CommonTitan"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
            >
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <local:MyControl x:Name="MyControl1" DataContext="{Binding MyControlCollection[8]}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <local:MyControl x:Name="MyControl2" DataContext="{Binding MyControlCollection[9]}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <local:MyControl x:Name="MyControl3" DataContext="{Binding MyControlCollection[10]}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>                   
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Appropriately (as far as i can tell) binds me to the items that i specify in a collection. In real use it will use an observable dictionary and those indexes are hash values that i won't be able to hand code in. Is it possible to pass in the 2 known parameters into some sort of converter in order to get the hash? or even pass in the 2 values to the converter which will end up returning the item out of the observable dictionary?

Comment: any chance to use ItemsControl instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass 2 known value as converter parameters, for example:

```xml
<local:MyControl x:Name="MyControl1" DataContext="{Binding MyControlCollection, Converter={StaticResource CollectionConverter}, ConverterParameters='8.9'}" />
```

And in your converter class you can use it here, parse the parameter as string:

```cs
public class CollectionConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            string[] param = (parameter as string).split('.');
            if (int.Parse(param[0]) == 8)
               return (value as ObservableCollection)[8];
            else
               return (value as ObservableCollection)[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("cannot cast the value");
    }
}
```